# Dynamically retrieve meta information about python classes declared in module/script

Tags: python, class, oop, metaprogramming

I have a set of classes which I would like to be able to dynamically initialise from dict.

```
class A(object):
    var = 1

class B(object):
    val = 2

class C(object):
    var = 1
    val = 3

BASE = {'a': A, 'b': B, 'c': C}
```

I might use these in some dynamic function such as

```
def create_and_obtain(kind, **kwargs):
    base = BASE[kind]()
    for kwarg in kwargs.keys():
        print(getattr(base, kwarg))
>>> create_and_obtain('c', var=None, val=None)
1
3
```

If I have a lot of classes, which are added, amended and removed from time to time, I must ensure that my `BASE` dict is kept up to date. Is there a way of dynamically constructing `BASE` according to the declared classes in the script? Can the classes themselves have any meta_attributes added that could be used to extend the definition of `BASE` beyond this simplistic example?

For example could I add some meta tags like:

```
class A(object):
    ...
    _meta_dict_key_ = 'apples'
class B(object):
    ...
    _meta_dict_key_ = 'bananas'
class C(object):
    ...
    _meta_dict_key_ = 'coconuts'
```

so that `BASE` is dynamically constructed as:

```
BASE = {'apples': A, 'bananas': B, 'coconuts':C}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has class decorators and so a clean way might be this:

```
BASE = {}

def register(klass):  # Uses an attribute of the class
    global BASE
    BASE[klass.name] = klass
    return klass

def label(name):  # Provide an explicit name
    def deco(klass):
        global BASE
        BASE[name] = klass
        return klass
    return deco

@register
class A(object):
    var = 1
    name = 'bananas'

@label('apples')
class B(object):
    val = 2

@register
class C(object):
    var = 1
    val = 3
    name = 'cakes'
```

Comment: You can also define the decorator so that it takes the name / key as an argument  instead of defining it as a property on the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the output of the `locals()` function at the end of the file and check _meta_dict_key. If there is such key in the object, you can use it to construct base dict.
In the python, all code that declared on the file top-level executes only once on the first import so it is safe to put such code there.